# JSTL retriving value with a dynamic variable name

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a situation where I am setting a link to an image in the session one one page to be accessed on another page, here is where it is set:

```
<c:set var="<%item.getCatalogEntryId()%>FTImage" value="${item.field5}" scope="session"/>
```

I'm having trouble pulling this info to be used on the second page, I want to do something like this, but the syntax is obviously off and I'm not sure how to correctly do this

```
<c:set var="CartImage" value="${sessionScope.${itemCatentryId}FTImage}"></c:set>
```

The catalogEntryId will be common between the two pages, I just need to know how to include it when retrieving the variable out of the session

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

try this .i think it will work

```
 <c:set var="CartImage" value="${sessionScope.[itemCatentryId]FTImage}"></c:set>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. I think a solution to your problem is to use a Map which will contain the `catalogEntryId` as key and the `item` as value. In case you have an `itemList` in your servlet/controller you could transform it to map using something like this:

```
// Servlet.
request.setAttribute("itemMap", itemList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(i-> String.valueOf(i.getCatalogEntryId()) + "FTImage", Function.identity())));
// Spring MVC Controller.
modelAndView.addObject("itemMap", itemList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(i-> String.valueOf(i.getCatalogEntryId()) + "FTImage", Function.identity())));
```

Thus, you will be able to use this map inside your views and get a dynamic key from your map like the above:

```
<c:set var="CartImage" value="${itemMap.get(item.getCatalogEntryId()+'FTImage')}" value="${your value}"></c:set>
```